# Android ActionBarActivity : Action Bar design not shown as expected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-studio, android-actionbaractivity

I am using Action Bar for one of my project. I used Appcompat Support Library version 21.0.0 for Action Bar and followed steps from here : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html.

But it doesn't look like what it is shown in the guide. The UP Button and Overflow menu button doesn't look like as shown in the above guide. Find the below images:

[image: Color in below image is Darker and the Overflow button shown is different that that shown in the guide.]

[image: Up Button shown is also different.]

I am using  compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'` and compile and Build version are as follows:

```
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.actionbar"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

I am using Theme.AppCompat.Light theme. Set from AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: The appcompat-v7:21 now has implemented the material design, and released the Toolbar which is a more generic implementation of the ActionBar. The guides are not updated yet with these elements so I recommend you to use appcompat-v7:20 instead if you want to have the action bar as it is in the guide.

Comment: Thanks. this solved this issue.

Comment: You're welcome, I'll post it as an answer then ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appcompat-v7:21 now has implemented the material design, and released the Toolbar which is a more generic implementation of the ActionBar. The guides are not updated yet with these elements so I recommend you to use appcompat-v7:20 instead if you want to have the action bar as it is in the guide.